# slideToggle bounces up and down

Tags: jquery, tabs, responsive-design, show-hide, slidetoggle

I'm trying to create a tabbed area with vertical tabs but when the screen is made smaller than 640px the tabs change in to an accordion style show/hide where multiple sections can be opened at one time.

Here is the jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/no4dvn3s/

When the page loads the tabs are to the left and the content on the right. If you make the screen smaller then the tabs become full width and the relevant content sits under each tab. When you click the tab title the content should slide down, however it currently bounces up and down a few time - any ideas what's causing it?

Also, if you refresh the page at the same screen size with the tabs full width then the bouncing action doesn't occur!

Here is my code - any help greatly appreciated!

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
@media only screen and (min-width:621px) {
#product #tabbed_area {height:auto; width:100%; overflow:hidden; margin-top:15px;}
#product #tabbed_area .tab_holder {height:auto; width:100%; overflow:hidden; margin-bottom:5px;}
#product #tabbed_area h3 {height:auto; width:30%; background:#d4d4d4 url(/Content/images/mobile_new/product/tab_off_state.png) 0 bottom repeat-x; border:1px solid #ebebeb; margin:0 0 5px 0; box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; font-family:'geometric_medium', arial; text-transform:uppercase; text-indent:10px; color:#000000; display:block; text-decoration:none; font-size:1.3em; padding:12px 0; position:relative;}
#product #tabbed_area h3:hover {cursor:pointer;}
#product #tabbed_area h3.active_tab {background:#580e3b url(/Content/images/mobile_new/product/tab_on_state.png) 0 bottom repeat-x; color:#ffffff;}
#product #tabbed_area h3 i {float:right; padding:12px 0 12px 0; position:absolute; right:15px; top:0;}
#product #tabbed_area .tab_content {display:none; margin:10px;}
#yourContainer {float:right; width:40%;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width:620px) {
#product #tabbed_area {height:auto; width:100%; overflow:hidden; margin-top:15px;}
#product #tabbed_area .tab_holder {height:auto; width:100%; overflow:hidden; margin-bottom:5px;}
#product #tabbed_area h3 {height:auto; width:100%; background:#d4d4d4 url(/Content/images/mobile_new/product/tab_off_state.png) 0 bottom repeat-x; border:1px solid #ebebeb; margin:0 0 5px 0; box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; font-family:'geometric_medium', arial; text-transform:uppercase; text-indent:10px; color:#000000; display:block; text-decoration:none; font-size:1.3em; padding:12px 0; position:relative;}
#product #tabbed_area h3:hover {cursor:pointer;}
#product #tabbed_area h3.active_tab {background:#580e3b url(/Content/images/mobile_new/product/tab_on_state.png) 0 bottom repeat-x; color:#ffffff;}
#product #tabbed_area h3 i {float:right; padding:12px 0 12px 0; position:absolute; right:15px; top:0;}
#product #tabbed_area .tab_content {display:none; margin:10px;}

}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://swimmingcover.co.uk/mobile.js"></script>

<div id="product">
    <div id="tabbed_area">
        <div class="tab_holder" id="tab1">
            <h3 class="tab_ttl active_tab">Tab1 <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></h3>
        </div>

        <div class="tab_holder" id="tab2">
            <h3 class="tab_ttl">Tab2 <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></h3>
        </div>

        <div class="tab_holder" id="tab3">
            <h3 class="tab_ttl">Tab3 <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></h3>
        </div>

        <div id="yourContainer">
            <div class="tab_content content1" id="about" style="display: block;">
                Tab1 Content
            </div>

            <div id="important" class="tab_content content2" style="display: none;">
                Tab2 Content
            </div>

            <div class="tab_content content3" id="location_list" style="display: none;">
                Tab3 Content
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think its working properly in the fiddle.. or i am not getting it

Comment: is [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/no4dvn3s/1/) what you wanted?

Comment: You need to resize the fiddle until the tabs are full width, the click on one of the tab names and the content bounces up and down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think i found the mistake. check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/no4dvn3s/5/)

When ever the window was re sized its attaching a new click event to the elements (instead of replacing the old click events).

replace

```
click({
```

with

```
.unbind('click').click({
```

this will remove the old click events and assign new ones.